# Munchkin "Shrieking Geek" Bad Stuff

Tags: munchkin

If you lose to the Shrieking Geek and fail to run away, the Bad Stuff that happens is described as:

> ***Bad Stuff:*** You become a normal boring Human. Discard any Race or Class cards in play.

If I have both a race and a class, do I lose both or only one?

Comment: Definitely both.

Comment: Hmmm... it says any cards *in play*, not any cards *you* have in play. So one could try to rule-lawyer that *all players* have to discard their race and class cards, not just the one bad stuff happens to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say both.

There is some room for interpretation here, due to ambiguities in the English language, but I would certainly interpret "any Race or Class cards in play" as equivalent to "all Race and Class cards in play."  (Note that you can have several of each, using cards like Half-Breed or Super Munchkin.)  This also matches the first part of the text, which says that you "become a normal boring Human"; if you didn't discard your Race cards, you would not become Human, and, at least arguably, if you did not discard your Classes, you would not become normal and boring.

If you were supposed to choose, it would most likely say something like "at least one Race or Class card of your choice," or maybe "either all Race or all Class cards in play."  But neither of those would really match the "become a normal boring Human" part.

Answer (score 3):

There is no room for interpretation. You must discard them both (or all if you have half-breed, super-munchkin or equivalents).

"Any race or class **card** in play" would mean you get to pick one to discard, and discard that one.

"Any race or class **cards** in play" means you have to discard all cards in play that meet the criteria.